# .NET Core 2.1 can't reference a .NET Framework 4.7.2 Class library

Tags: .net, .net-core

I have a .NET Core 2.1 app, a .NET MVC website (4.7.2) and I also have a .NET 4.7.2 class library.

What I'm trying to do is have my core 2.1 project reference the class library.

Now I've added the reference to the core project with no issues (it builds), but when I try to add the namespace to a class It doesn't come up.

I want both the app and the MVC site to share the same class library.

Here's the screen shot:

[image: There should be another namespace, one called models]

There should be another namespace, one called models

Any help would be great. 
Thanks

Comment: does the .net framework library conform to the .net standard?

Comment: I believe so, It uses some additional nuget packages. What's the best way I can figure it out? Thanks

Answer (score 13, accepted):

**You can reference `.NET Standard` library instead**. So you need to create `.NET Standard` library with common shared logic and reference it **from both - `.NET Core` and `.NET Framework ("full")` projects.**

Note that while you may be able to use `.NET Standard` without `PackageReference`, it's recommended to do it this way. Find more details in [Referencing .NET Standard Assemblies from both .NET Core and .NET Framework](https://www.hanselman.com/blog/ReferencingNETStandardAssembliesFromBothNETCoreAndNETFramework.aspx).

Comment: That did it, Thanks :)

Comment: This indeed work, but I also needed to add the `<RestoreProjectStyle>PackageReference</RestoreProjectStyle>` to the `<PropertyGroup>` in the csproj file. See [S. Hanselman](https://www.hanselman.com/blog/ReferencingNETStandardAssembliesFromBothNETCoreAndNETFramework.aspx) and finally for more issues [this](https://github.com/dotnet/standard/issues/481).