# Is it possible to run ASP .NET MVC 5 on the .NET Core platform?

Tags: c#, asp.net, .net, asp.net-mvc, .net-core

Is it possible to run ASP .NET MVC 5 on the .NET Core platform, or at least reference .NET Core libraries from an ASP .NET MVC 5 application?

The reason I'm asking for this is that I have a ASP .NET MVC 5 application running on the .NET Framework, but I want to migrate the back end code to .NET Core, mainly because [C# 8.0 is not going to be released for the .NET Framework](https://devblogs.microsoft.com/dotnet/an-update-to-c-versions-and-c-tooling/), and I want to make use of C# 8 in the back end code.

Comment: Consider using .NET Standard, that's a meeting point between .NET Framework and .NET Core (meaning that enables you to write code compatible both with Core and the "old" framework)

Comment: this link is helpful:https://stackoverflow.com/questions/52407001/net-core-2-1-cant-reference-a-net-framework-4-7-2-class-library

Comment: @moro91 That won't help, because .NET Standard 2.1 (which corresponds to .NET Core 3.0, i.e. the version that runs C# 8.0) will not be supported by the .NET Framework any time soon. (Check link in the OP)

Answer (score 2):

You can't run your project ASP.NET MVC 5 in .NET Core.
You have to migrate your project to ASP.NET Core.

Microsoft has documented the process here : https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/aspnet/core/migration/mvc?view=aspnetcore-3.0