# Referencing .NetCore project from .Net Framework

Tags: .net-core, .net-framework-version

.Net Core version (2.0+)
.Net Framework version 4.5+
, Visual studio 2019

Currently i have an issue where the UI is made in .Net framework but the back end code is currently in .net Core.

I looked at standard and it looks like .Net core can reference standard but not the other way around.

Aside from converting the UI to Core or the backend to .Net framework. Is there a way around this issue?

Currently the two (.net framework and core) do not communicate with each other.

What i have is a .Net framework legacy monolith application, which has been revamped in core (but no UI). In the future we'll go web/ cross platform but  temporary we'd like the new core code to connect with Desktop Ui as the UI is going to take some time to complete.

Regards

Comment: Dlls built targeting `.Net Standard` should be available for both .Net Framework and Core, https://stackoverflow.com/questions/52407001/net-core-2-1-cant-reference-a-net-framework-4-7-2-class-library

Comment: This is a troubled area and most likely you won't be able to do it as simple as that, but if you can you add more details (such as: .Net version of the "main" project) perhaps we can provided a workaround

Comment: Sow how is your UI communicating with the back end? If it is written in different frameworks (.net vs .net core), is there a communication mechanism you can use?

Comment: Hi, i've modified original post for more details of what's happening

Comment: .NET Core and Full .NET both are implementations of .NET Standard, but they not able to "communicate" with each other. Instead you can introduce .NET Standard library which both .NET Core and Full .NET can consume.

Answer (score 0):

Unfortunately this will not play out exactly as you hope for.

First of all, make sure your projects are targeting .net Standard.

Second, check out [this blog here](https://weblog.west-wind.com/posts/2019/Feb/19/Using-NET-Standard-with-Full-Framework-NET). Theres a matrix of support and compatibility.

Good luck on your endeavor!