# Is it possible to build a C# project as a .Netcore application if it has a .Netframework dependencies

Tags: c#, .net, .net-core

I have a `.NetCore` application that is fully portable (working as cross-platform). Now, I need to refer to and use a `.Netframework` library that I would be using its functionalities if and only if my application is running on `Windows` device.

I found that It is possible through making the project's `.csproj` configuration file targets multiple SDKs (Both `.NetCore` and `.NetFramework`) like this `<TargetFrameworks>net472;netcoreapp2.1</TargetFrameworks>`.

My question is, does building my application to target multiple frameworks (like the case above) keeps it portable (works on both Windows and Linux)?

**Edit:**

Someone marked this question as a duplicate for another question that was answered as using `.Netstandard` would solve the problem. I still can't see how.

In my case, I have an already built `.netframework` class library that I don't have its source code, so I can't translate it into `.netstandard` and simply use it.

I need to use `.Netframework` class library directly in my `.NetCore` application if it is running under Windows, is this possible?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [.NET Core 2.1 can't reference a .NET Framework 4.7.2 Class library](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/52407001/net-core-2-1-cant-reference-a-net-framework-4-7-2-class-library)

Comment: .Net framework 4.7.2 does not work on Linux (full stop)

Comment: @Liam I need to use the .Netframework functions only if I'm on windows

Answer (score 4):

No. You need to use a [.NET Standard](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/standard/net-standard) class library instead:

> The .NET Standard enables the following key scenarios
>
> - Defines uniform set of BCL APIs for all .NET implementations to implement, independent of workload.
> - Enables developers to produce portable libraries that are usable across .NET implementations, using this same set of APIs.
> - Reduces or even eliminates conditional compilation of shared source due to .NET APIs, only for OS APIs.