# Operation is not supported on this platform

Tags: c#, .net-core, asp.net-core-2.0

I have a simple project with `.NetFramework 3.5 Class library`.

I compile and run `c# dynamic code` at the `runtime` (with `CodeDom`) in the `.NetFramework` project and call  from the `Asp.NetCore 2.0` project.

when I call the `BuildAssembly` Method in `Common` class from `Asp.NetCore 2.0` project, I encounter with this Error: (CodeDom throws)

> "System.PlatformNotSupportedException":"Operation is not supported on
>   this platform." at Microsoft.CSharp.CSharpCodeGenerator.FromFileBatch(CompilerParameters options, String[] fileNames) at Microsoft.CSharp.CSharpCodeGenerator.System.CodeDom.Compiler.ICodeCompiler.CompileAssemblyFromSourceBatch(CompilerParameters options, String[] sources)

following code:

**.NetFrameWork 3.5:**

```
public class Common
{
    public Assembly BuildAssembly(string code)
    {
        CodeDomProvider codeProvider = CodeDomProvider.CreateProvider("CSharp");
        CompilerParameters compilerparams = new CompilerParameters();
        compilerparams.GenerateExecutable = false;//Generate an executable instead of a class library
        compilerparams.GenerateInMemory = false; //Save the assembly as a physical file.

        compilerparams.ReferencedAssemblies.Add("mscorlib.dll");
        compilerparams.ReferencedAssemblies.Add("System.dll");
        compilerparams.ReferencedAssemblies.Add("System.Data.dll");
        compilerparams.ReferencedAssemblies.Add("System.Xml.dll");

        CompilerResults results = codeProvider.CompileAssemblyFromSource(compilerparams, code);
        if (results.Errors.HasErrors)
        {
            StringBuilder errors = new StringBuilder("Compiler Errors :\r\n");
            foreach (CompilerError error in results.Errors)
            {
                errors.AppendFormat("Line {0},{1}\t: {2}\n",
                        error.Line, error.Column, error.ErrorText);
            }
            throw new Exception(errors.ToString());
        }
        else
        {
            return results.CompiledAssembly;
        }
    }
}
```

**Asp.NetCore 2.0:**

```
public IActionResult Test()
{
    string code = @"
using System;
using System.Text;
using System.Data;
using System.Reflection;
using System.ComponentModel;

namespace testNameSpace
{
    public class DynamicClass
    {
         public string Test() {     return ""Hello world""; }
    }
}";
    var res = new Common().BuildAssembly(code);
    return Json("ok");
}
```

I searched at the web and accoding this [Link](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/37526165/compiling-and-running-code-at-runtime-in-net-core-1-0) I install the `Microsoft.CodeAnalysis.CSharp` nuget package and tested but It's not working.

I can not compile the simple code from this way.

how to fix this error?

Comment: Is there a reason why you're trying to consume a .NET Framework library in a .NET Core application? Why not just make a .NET Framework application? Or make a .NET Core/.NET Standard library?

Comment: nice, Because the `.Net Framework` application is already manufactured. and in the `Web` Application, We use the `Asp.Net Core`.
and We do not want to rewrite the generated code.

Comment: [Related question 1](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/52407001/net-core-2-1-cant-reference-a-net-framework-4-7-2-class-library), [related question 2](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/52703060/referencing-net-framework-4-dll-in-net-core-2-0)

Comment: thanks @john, but the `.Net Framework` library referenced to `Asp.Net Core` Project without error.
error accurse that when to Execute the `BuildAssembly` Method at line `CompilerResults results = codeProvider.CompileAssemblyFromSource(compilerparams, code);`

Comment: So all other methods in the .NET Framework library work when called from .NET Core except for this one?

Comment: Yes,all of method working well, this method run the `string Code` at runtime and has error in `runtime`.